# How to set values for properties tag of maven by reading the .properties file

Tags: maven

I have 5 projects, here I want to copy the java classes from one non-maven project to maven project for this requirement I used maven-ant-plugin. with this I am able to do the copy successfully.

> pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project1_maven.src.main.java>c:/maven1/src/main/java</project1_maven.src.main.java>
        <project1_maven.src.test.java>c:/maven1/src/test/java</project1_maven.src.test.java>

        <project1.nonmaven.src>c:/non-maven1/src</project1.nonmaven.src>
        <project1.nonmaven.test>c:/non-maven1/test</project1.nonmaven.test>

    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy file="${project1.nonmaven.src}"
                                    todir="${project1_maven.src.main.java}" />
                                <copy file="${project1.nonmaven.test}"
                                    todir="${project1_maven.src.test.java}" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>



        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

But here my question is, instead of giving the source and destination paths (I want to give this like for remaining 4 projects) inside the `pom.xml` directly, I just want to read it from the properties file.

for example : 
`<project1.nonmaven.src>
        ${get the location from property bundle by using key}</project1.nonmaven.src>`

Can you please some one suggest me how ??

Thanks.

Comment: First follow maven conventions and put source code into `src/main/java` and test code into `src/test/java`...Furthermore remove aboslute paths under any circumstances from your pom file...

Comment: @ khmarbaise pom updated, but I need to keep absoulute as the same. Because I'm trying to merging the code with using the above pom. and this pom is in separate project. actually I just want to fetch those absolute paths from some properties file, that's what my intention all about....Thanks.